# Selenium XPath of preceding element

Tags: selenium

I have a scenario wherein the html tags are generated dynamically through ajax as shown below

```
<div>
   <span class="rptName">QLMS</span>
   <span id="button_id_91">//generated dynamically
     <span id="button_span_right_91">    
       <span id="button_91"/>
     </span>
   </span>
   <span class="rptName">QLRS</span>
   <span id="button_id_92">//generated dynamically
     <span id="button_span_right_92">    
       <span id="button_92"/>
     </span>
   </span>
</div>
```

The span elements are generated dynamically, in such scenarios how do we get the xpath based on the text search(QLMS,QLRS present in span).
I need to do an click event on the

> `<span id="button_92" or "91"/>`

Please let me know how to achieve in such scenario.

Comment: In the sample it looks like the `class` of the target `span`s are static - if it's really so, the simplest approach would be `//div/span[@class="rptName"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems pretty tricky. Using [following-sibling](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) should help. I am also filtering out the `span` with the partial `id` *right*. Try this:

```
//span[contains(text(),'QLRS')]/following-sibling::span//span[not(contains(@id,'right'))]
```